# Best way for Java application cross platform when library have file for each platform?

Tags: java, platform, chilkat

I usually use chilkat library (http://www.chilkatsoft.com/java.asp) develop only with windows. but this library have each library file for each platform, and today I have to do it cross platform.

**Example**

- Windows x64 use win64.dll
- Windows x84 use win32.dll
- Linux x64 use linux64.so
- Linux x32 use linux32.so
- Max OSX use osx.jnilib

This my source code for include chilkat library when use windows only.

```
static {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("lib/win64");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
        try {
            System.loadLibrary("lib/win32");
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e2) {
            System.err.println("Native code library failed to load.\n" + e2);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

And now I no idea. How include each library file on java application for cross platform ?

Please guide best way to me.

Thank you.

Edit1: sorry for confusion. i know how find os.name on runtime. but this question i mean how include each library file for run each platform.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JarSplice and create multiple jars for many platforms. http://ninjacave.com/jarsplice

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `os.name` `System` property to determine what OS you are running on...

```
 String os = System.getProperty("os.name");
 if (os.startsWith("Mac")) {
     // Running on Mac
 } else if (os.startsWith("Windows")) {
     // Running on Windows
 }
```

Sorry, don't have a Linux box to test on ;)

On Windows, you can try testing the `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` environment variable, which when running within a x64 bit process state, should return `AMD64`

Comment: sorry for confusion. i know how find os.name on runtime. but this question i mean how include each library file for run each platform.

Comment: Include all of them, load the one you need based on the OS...

Comment: You mean, i can use "System.loadLibrary("lib/osx.jnilib");" on Mac and "System.loadLibrary("lib/linux64.so");" on Linux when know os name running ?

Comment: I would, but that's me.  You could setup separate "distributions" which only included the required library(s), but I would make the code used to load them the same